# make body minimized for special monitor sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is an image that describe how it is look like in 15 inches monitor

[image]

& this image is related to when i minimized my browser screen whit (ctrl + -)

[image]

My website has good view in 20 inches monitors,but in 15 inches monitors it isn't look good, so I have to minimize my screen with (ctrl + - ) and then its looks great!

```css
body {
      background-image: url(../../img/darkbg.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
}

html, body, .container-table {
      height: 100%;
}
```

I'll be thankful if anybody can give me any suggestion for this.

Comment: background image or everything?

Comment: can you provide website url or snapshot how its looks in 15 inches monitor ?

Comment: @Dejan.S every thing... & i now added 2 images that describes what i want exactly

Comment: @user7357089 i add 2 images,do you have an idea for it?

Comment: @Solo  my center image should to have 980x600 px; i want to write sth that read what sizes is my screen and then if it is 1366 x 768 ,then whole of my page being minimized

Comment: & beacuse of my center image should to have that static size i can not to resize it...

Comment: Are u using bootstrap to your webpage? please don't use (ctrl + -) to check the website resolution, use firefox press ctrl+shift+m . Please provide your working url to better understanding !

Comment: I believe you mean zoom out, not minimize. Minimizing a window would make it disappear, so it wouldn't look like anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean background image try background-size property.

```
body{
  background-image: url(../../img/darkbg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

This will make background image adjust with browser width automatically.
For more read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size